# [AppGalleryConnectLinkManageService]the ios bundleId does not have permission

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

i wrote a method to generate link using Applinking Huawei

```
  fun generateLink(text: String, promo: String): Single<String> = Single.create { emitter ->
    AppLinking.newBuilder()
            .setUriPrefix(Const.Deeplink.BASE_URL_APPLINKING)
            .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(Const.Deeplink.BASE_WEB + addParams(mapOf(Const.Deeplink.PARAM_PROMOCODE to promo))))
            .setAndroidLinkInfo(AppLinking.AndroidLinkInfo.newBuilder()
                    .setAndroidDeepLink(AGS + Const.Deeplink.PACKAGE_NAME_ANDROID)
                    .build()
            )
            .setIOSLinkInfo(AppLinking.IOSLinkInfo.newBuilder()
                    .setIOSDeepLink(AGS + Const.Deeplink.PACKAGE_NAME_IOS)
                    .setBundleId(Const.Deeplink.PACKAGE_NAME_IOS)
                    .build()
            )
            .buildShortAppLinking(ShortAppLinking.LENGTH.SHORT)
            .addOnSuccessListener { link ->
                Timber.e("${link.testUrl}")
                text.plus("\n").plus(link.shortUrl?.toString()).also {
                    emitter.onSuccess(it)
                    Timber.e(it)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                var dr = Const.Deeplink.PACKAGE_NAME_ANDROID
                var df = Uri.parse(Const.Deeplink.BASE_WEB + addParams(mapOf(Const.Deeplink.PARAM_PROMOCODE to promo)))
                emitter.onError(it)

            }
}
```

but a have error

```
com.huawei.agconnect.applinking.AppLinkingException:  code: 204865654 message: [AppGalleryConnectLinkManageService]the ios bundleId does not have permission
```

has anyone come across this?
PACKAGE_NAME_IOS is valid com.65gb.xxxxx.xxxxx

after when work
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You need to integrate the AppLinking iOS SDK into your iOS project whose bundleID is com.65gb.xxxx.xxxx, and then use the handleAppLinking interface to receive and obtain the configured iOSDeepLink.

For details about how to receive AppLinking in iOS, see the [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-receivelinks-ios-0000001054025701#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001152875737__section19694125123217).

[image]

---

Ensure that the package ID of your iOS app is the same as the parameter passed using the `setBundleId()` method. You can view the package ID in AppGallery Connect.

App Linking is used for all apps under a project. You can implement redirections only between apps whose package names are in the same project in AppGallery Connect.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then in AppGallery Connect I somehow have to add an IOS application, we have a similar thing for Firebase and I mean that Ios is there, but I don't quite understand how in AppGallery Connect add IOS

Comment: Hi@АлексKnight,you can refer this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started-ios#h1-1587536766603). [Adding an App to the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qHtG.jpg)

Comment: hi @shirley, yes, I already found it myself, thanks more for the help, my friend programmer, I will try to set it up further

Comment: Should you need help with anything else, please feel free to reach out back to us. :D

Comment: oh gods, it all worked !! Yes, I have one more question. By your docks
 .setIOSDeepLink ("agckit: // example / detail")

how the line should look correctly if the name is bundle ios com.65gb.xxxx.xxxx

Comment: or this line must  setIOSDeepLink ("agckit: //"IOS APP Store ID"/ detail")

Comment: setIOSDeepLink ("agckit: //"IOS APP Store ID"/ detail")   it is just a example, not must.

Comment: Hi@АлексKnight,I just updated my answer,pls kindly refer that.

Comment: yes, I saw everything my friend the programmer, but the question arose about the processing of the link itself, if the person does not have the iOS application installed, safari gives an error, though if you press ok then everything is fine. I just updated my question,pls kindly refer that